# Splitting a boxed slice in two owned halves

Tags: vector, rust, split, slice

**My problem**

I have a boxed slice `s: Box<[Something]>` that I would like to split into two owned halves, e.g., `s1: Box<[Something]>` containing the first `s.len()/2` elements of `s`, and `s2: Box<[Something]>` containing the rest.

**With `Vec`s**

I know something along these lines can be achieved if `s: Vec<Something>`, using `s.split_off()`. However, what `split_off` does is it creates a new `t: Vec<Something>`, moves `s.len()/2` elements from `s` to `t`, then shrinks `s`. While this obviously works, it does not feel very efficient.

**Unsafely speaking**

If I were writing in C, what I would is just take a pointer to the middle of `s`, call it `t` and unsafely ride into the sunset. I am wondering if something like this can be done in Rust too.

(One issue that I see with the above C-style approach is that, while `s` can be freed, `t` cannot. So `s` and `t` would not be exactly the same, as one of the two would need to be freed, while the other should just be dropped. But, I could imagine this information being carried in some flag attached to `s` and `t`.)

Comment: Obviously you can [split a slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut), but I don't think there's anything in the standard library that will split ownership, for the very reasons you touch upon in your closing parenthesis: when dropping a `Box`, it is returned to the allocator, but there is only one allocation to be released here.  No doubt there are third party crates that can give you ownership of something that tracks when both sides of the split are dropped and only then releases the allocation, or you could implement that yourself fairly easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can't split `Box<[T]>` apart in place. Your C example seems to have undefined behaviour.

Imagine next `split_in_place` function:

```rust
let all = Box::new([1,2,3,4]);
let (left: Box<[i32]>, right: Box<[i32]>) = all.split_in_place(2);

println!("{:?}", left); // seems to be ok
std::mem::drop(left);
println!("{:?}", right); // undefined behaviour here. `left` was dropped, so the entire memory of the initial `Box` is dropped and `right` is an invalid pointer.
```

What you can do is use sub-slices of a slice:

```
let all = Box::new([1,2,3,4]);

let (left, right) = all.split_at(2);

println!("{:?}", left); // [1, 2]
std::mem::drop(left);
println!("{:?}", right); // [3, 4]
```

If you need to mutate parts, you can use `split_at_mut`:

```
let mut all = Box::new([1,2,3,4]);

let (left, right) = all.split_at_mut(2);

for i in left.iter_mut() {
  *i += 1;
  for j in right.iter_mut() {
    *j += *i; // you can borrow mutably both parts at the same time
  }
}

println!("{:?}", left);
std::mem::drop(left);
println!("{:?}", right);
```

Comment: Actually, your `split_in_place` would work, if it copies the sub-slices into two new allocations (i.e. new boxes). Tho, I guess this is not what OP meant to do.

Comment: If it copies parts of original slice, then it is not a splitting in place. It makes two new allocations + probably cloning which is not cheap.

Answer (score 0):

You can't split a `Box<[T]>` in two `Box<[T]>`s. The allocator simply don't allow that.

You can however achieve something similar to what you want using `Rc<[T]>` (or `Arc` if needed). This approach is similar to your C-style using-a-flag approach, except that both parts of the slice share ownership.

Here is an example for non-mutable slices:

```rust
use core::ops::Deref;
use core::ops::Range;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct SharedSplitSlice<T> {
    range: Range<usize>,
    buffer: Rc<[T]>,
}

impl<T> Deref for SharedSplitSlice<T> {
    type Target = [T];
    
    #[inline(always)]
    fn deref(&self) -> &[T] {
        &self.buffer[self.range.clone()]
    }
}

fn split<T>(b: Box<[T]>, split_at: usize) -> (SharedSplitSlice<T>, SharedSplitSlice<T>) {
    let b = Rc::<[T]>::from(b);
    
    (
        SharedSplitSlice {
            range: 0..split_at,
            buffer: b.clone(),
        },
        SharedSplitSlice {
            range: split_at..b.len(),
            buffer: b,
        },
    )
}

fn main() {
    let b = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].into_boxed_slice();
    
    let (h, t) = split(b, 2);
    
    println!("{:?}", &*h);
    println!("{:?}", &*t);
}
```

Comment: This is cool...! However, am I correct in my understanding that I could not get a mutable reference to an element of `h` and an element of `t` at the same time? Like, `h` and `t` are still somehow linked by the `Rc` they share, so they cannot be mutated independently of each other, as if they were in distinct boxed slices. Correct?

Comment: You could add support for this, using `Rc::as_ptr` and `slice::from_raw_parts` to make the `mut`-subslice. It would require `unsafe`, but as long as you check all the bounds and the method takes `&mut self`, it would be safe.

Comment: This would be very interesting...! Can you elaborate a bit how I could do it?